# How to get plotly.express.timeline overlapped bars to be visible

Tags: python, plotly, timeline

I'd like to know if anyone has a solution to overlapping timeline bars?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-02-25', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-23', Finish='2009-05-23', Resource="Max"),
    dict(Task="Job D", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource="Max")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Resource", color="Resource")
fig.show()
```

[image]

And in the image it's very difficult to see:

- Where Job A ends/Job B starts
- Job D is not visible at all

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be fine with different colors for all of the jobs?

Comment: @AS11 not in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often find that assigning different `width` to some of the categories helps make the whole thing easier to read. So in your case I would include a column in your `df` where this is specified, and then edit the figure using:

```
for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    d.width = df[df['Task']==d.name]['width']
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code with edited data:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

resource = ['Alex', 'Max']
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex", width = 0.5),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-02-25', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Alex", width = 0.2),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-23', Finish='2009-05-23', Resource="Max", width = 0.5),
    dict(Task="Job D", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource="Max", width = 0.2)
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Resource", color="Task")

for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    d.width = df[df['Task']==d.name]['width']
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think this will work for my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can update layout by this command:

```
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
```

[image: Your traces will be grouped as here]

Answer (score 2):

The best that I was able to figure out was using different colors for all of the `"Tasks"` or `"Jobs"`, and having to `opacity` lower so that it was possible to see the traces/bars that were getting covered

The code looks like:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-02-25', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-23', Finish='2009-05-23', Resource="Max"),
    dict(Task="Job D", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource="Max")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Resource", color="Task", opacity=0.5)

fig.show()
```

And the graph looks like:
[image]

Comment: It's a valid solution for some cases, but will get a bit cluttered in some scenarios. Thank you for the suggestion and it might come handy in the future!