# Plotly Gantt Chart: Remove Duplicate Y-Axis Labels and Stack Parallel Tasks

Tags: python, plotly, gantt-chart

I'm planning on using the python library 'Plotly' to build a Gantt Chart. Specifically this: https://plotly.com/python/gantt/#group-tasks-together.

However, each "Job" could have multiple tasks and these tasks could be running in parallel. From what I have observed Plotly doesn’t stack tasks running in parallel on top of each other making it incredibly hard to read the chart. Here is an example where "Job A" has two tasks running in parallel but only one is visible:

```
data = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')]

# Without group_tasks=True, There would be two separate "Job A" labels
fig = ff.create_gantt(data, group_tasks=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

What I want is both "Job A" tasks to be visible but stacked vertically with "Job A" sitting in the center of the vertical space taken up by its tasks. Something like this but without two "Job A" labels:

[image]

If anyone has any library recommendations I should consider for my Gantt Chart project please feel free to share! Thank you!

Comment: I tried your data in [Altair's](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/gantt_chart.html) library and Job A did not aggregate into two tasks. It depends on how you think of tasks, but if there is the same task for the same amount of time, wouldn't the job names be Job A-1 and Job A-2?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to play around with this data! Let me put the data into a perspective that will make sense. Imagine each "Job" is a restaurant and each task (bar) is an order being placed with the duration of how long it took to cook and serve the dish. Restaurants move in an asynchronous fashion so they have multple tasks running in parallel and often overlapping each other. These tasks are ALWAYS unique and should never be hidden. Does this help?

Comment: Would you be fine with another way to make this work than vertically stacking? The solutions on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129085/how-to-get-plotly-express-timeline-overlapped-bars-to-be-visible/67130018#67130018 work with a timeline (which I assume could be used in your case), and should even work with the gantt charts.

Comment: I found this example: https://community.plotly.com/t/group-by-color-in-px-timeline/51049

That is exactly what I want. How can I accomplish this as it must be possible using Plotly?

Comment: My guess is that you will need some workaround such as using an annotation, or shapes to manually place the bars for `Job A` in the correct configuration over the rest of the figure. I'll circle back to this later if no one has answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point would be to use `fig.add_shape` to add an identical `Task` as a rectangle below the original `Task`.

To do this, we need the y-coordinates of each rectangle, but conveniently, the first bar will be at y=0, the second bar at y=1, and so on. Therefore, the index of the unique tasks listed in order is also the y-coordinate (The unique tasks are `[Job A, Job B, Job C]` so the Job C bar will be centered at `y=3`). The default width of each bar is 0.8, so y1 should end at `y0-0.4` if y0 is the starting y-coordinate of the bar.

Note that there won't be any hovertemplate for the annotated shapes and the color is the same for each bar the way it is written currently.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## added additional duplicate Task to demonstrate generalizability
data = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Without group_tasks=True, There would be two separate "Job A" labels
# fig = ff.create_gantt(data, group_tasks=True)

## plot the non-duplicate rows
fig = px.timeline(df.loc[~df['Task'].duplicated()], x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")

## plot the duplicate rows using rectangular shapes
for row in df.loc[df['Task'].duplicated()].itertuples():
      y_val = np.where(df.Task.unique()==row[1])[0][0]
      # print(f"found {row[1]} at index {y_val}")
      fig.add_shape(type="rect",
            xref="x", yref="y",
            x0=row[2], x1=row[3], 
            y0=y_val, y1=y_val-0.4,
            line_width=0,
            fillcolor="salmon",
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['JobNum'] = ""
df.loc[0,'JobNum'] = 1
for idx in range(1,df.shape[0]):
    if df.loc[idx-1,'Task'] == df.loc[idx,'Task']:
        df.loc[idx,'JobNum'] = df.loc[idx-1,'JobNum'] + 1
    else:
        df.loc[idx,'JobNum'] = 1

df['hoverName'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Task'] + "|" + str(x['JobNum']), axis=1)
```

Approach 1: Using Facet row

```
fig = px.timeline(df
                  , x_start="Start"
                  , x_end="Finish"
                  , y="Task"
                  , hover_name= "Task"
                  , color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Prism
                  , opacity=.7
                  , template='plotly_white'
                  , color='Task'
                  , facet_row= 'JobNum'
                  , hover_data = ['Start','Finish']
                 )
fig.show()
```

[Appraoch 1 Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO14g.png)

Appraoch 2: Adjusting width and offset. This needs to be generalized when the there are more than two parallel tasks.

```
fig = px.timeline(df
                  , x_start="Start"
                  , x_end="Finish"
                  , y="Task"
                  , hover_name= "hoverName"
                  , color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Prism
                  , opacity=.7
                  , template='plotly_white'
                  , color='JobNum'
                  , hover_data = ['Start','Finish']
                 )

for obj in fig.data:
    Task, JobNum = obj.hovertext[0].split("|")
    if (int(JobNum) == 1):
        obj.width = 0.1
        obj.offset = 0.05
    elif (int(JobNum) == 2):
        obj.width = 0.1
        obj.offset = -0.05

fig.show()
```

[Approach 2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adD1t.png)