# Gantt parallel subjobs

Tags: python, plotly, gantt-chart

I am trying to plot a peculiar sort of Gantt graph. In my Gantt graph, I need to plot in the same y-axis job item multiple jobs occurring parallelly. For example, let's take the code snippet below, taken from some [Plotly examples](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/).

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

The code above generates the following Gantt graph.

[image: Gantt graph example]

I am trying to generate a Gantt graph that contains "subjobs", for example, let's take Job A, and after Job A add two more Jobs being executed in parallel, resulting in the following graph, where the two added jobs are represented by the colors red and green.

[image]

I would like to know how to plot such sort of Gantt graph. If anyone has any insight on this, your insight would be gladly received. Also, case you know another strategy relying on other tools, different than Plotly, please feel free to point it out.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67740227/2529954) should help.